# Convert var to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have var item which I want to convert in to a Datatable.
How can I do this.

```
var items =  (from myObj in this.Context.Orders
                     group myObj by myObj.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy-mm")
                     into ymGroup
                     select new { Date = ymGroup.Key, Start = ymGroup.Min(c => c.OrderId), End = ymGroup.Max(c => c.OrderId) });
```

I need to convert the items into a DataTable. I don't want to use any foreach loop.
How can I do this.?

Comment: Just to let you know, var isn't a type, it allows you to work with strongly typd items without actually having to type out what they are.  This will return `IEnumerable<AnonymousType1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on:http:[//www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx)